# JS: 6 Different options and one "Proceed" Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with 6 different options. They're NOT in a dropdown.
They're sort of like boxes that you can tick. I want it so that if I tick one of the options (let's say I tick the first box) and click "Proceed" I'm brought to a seperate page for that option. If i tick as an example box 3 and click "Proceed" I'm brought to a seperate page for option 3.

Comment: Learn JavaScript and HTML. PHP is not required.

Comment: Couldn't add the JavaScript tag. Can you help me?

Comment: What you have here is not a code problem, it's a solution problem which we don't really support. We're here to help with concrete bugs and problems in code. Not write the code for you. What we can do is to help you get an identifier for which one has been clicked, but you need to write the rest yourself; Aka. the page you want to go to and so on.

Answer (score 0):

give each checkbox a name parameter (the same) and a different value parameter
then post your form to a PHP script or use JavaScript to interpret the value and use the location object in the submit event handler

```
<form onsubmit="location=this.chk.value">
<label>abcd<input name=chk type=checkbox value="http://"></label>
<label>abcd<input name=chk type=checkbox value="http://"></label>
<label>abcd<input name=chk type=checkbox value="http://"></label>
<input type=submit value=proceed>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide some snippets so it's easier for me to understand?